# Selenium, Python - Difficulty selecting elements with XPath expressions

Tags: python, selenium, automation

im having a problem

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome( 
executable_path=r'C:\Users\Michelle\Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
#opens website%
driver.get("https://www.ebay.com")
#selects search bar and enters keys
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("gh-ac")
inputElement.send_keys('headphones')
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
Items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="srp-river-results- 
listing1"]/div/div[2]/a/h3')
Prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="srp-river-results- 
listing1"]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/span')
print(Items[0].text + " : " + Prices[0].text)


driver.close()
```

okay im trying to get ebay to display the name and prices of the item
but after going to the page and looking at the xpath of the prices they are all different

```
//*[@id="srp-river-results-listing1"]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/span
//*[@id="srp-river-results-listing2"]/div/div[2]
//*[@id="srp-river-results-listing3"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span
 ^ the xpaths
```

how else would i get them to display the prices other than xpath, is there way like using elements?

```
<span class="s-item__price">$99.00</span>
```

using element like this^?

Comment: Please take some effort to properly describe your problem with clear and concise title

Comment: i spent about 10 minutes doing that with my lack  of experience not really a better way to explaim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and was getting no results with your xpath expressions, try the following with simpler CSS selector expressions:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def main():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Michelle\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.maximize_window()

    try:
        driver.get("https://www.ebay.com")

        input_element = driver.find_element_by_id("gh-ac")
        input_element.send_keys('headphones')
        input_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.srp-results .s-item .s-item__title')
        prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.srp-results .s-item .s-item__price')

        print("# Items: %d" % len(items))
        print("# Prices: %d" % len(prices))

        print(items[5].text + " : " + prices[5].text)

    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
# Items: 60
# Prices: 60
2PCS New Headphones Earphones With Remote & Mic For Apple iPhone 6S 6 5 5S 4S : $28.97
```

Comment: you really do not know how much  i appreciate this. I guess all That really can be done is say Thank you.

Comment: the goal for this is to be able to make it so when you take a picture it gives you an accurate scale of what the item is selling for on ebay of course im a long way from this